# Blogger OpenID not working again

Tags: support, status-completed, openid

Iam getting the following error when trying to login using blogger open id.

> Unable to log in with your OpenID
>   provider:
>
> No OpenID endpoint found.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We apologize for the inconvenience -- this was a configuration error on our end -- try now!

Comment: Yup, now it works. (I use a private installation of Gracie for my OpenID provider, and it also stopped working.)